# Write content to file with Automator

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator

I'm building an Automator Service to create an `.html` file and write some text in it.

I've managed to create my `.html` file by using the **New Text File** action, but how can I write text in it?

I see no action for that effect, so I guess I should go with something like AppleScript, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your text file with TextEdit, which allows you to write text to the document with the "Set Contents of TextEdit Document" action.